# How to add check-boxes to a dynamically created tabpage and then link a groupbox with each checkbox (VB.NET)?

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, tabcontrol

(Part 1) I want to add 8 checkboxes to every dynamically created tabpage. I tried following but it adds a check box on the last tabpage. How to add 8 chckboxes to every tab page (say 10 tab pages)

(Part 2) Since we do not know the index of checkbox created, I am unable to understand how to link a groupbox with a "checkbox.checked" condition. Any help will be really appreciated.

```
Dim chkbx As New CheckBox

For j = 1 To 10 '#10 tab pages considered
Form4.TabControl1.TabPages.Add(j)
Form4.TabControl1.TabPages(j).Text = "Folder" & j + 1
Form4.TabControl1.TabPages(j).Controls.Add(chkbx)
chkbx.Text = "folder1name "
chkbx.Size = New Size(220, 17)
Next (j)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create CheckBox instance each time in `for` loop

```
For j = 0 To 9 '#10 tab pages considered
  Dim chkbx As New CheckBox
  Form4.TabControl1.TabPages.Add(j)
  Form4.TabControl1.TabPages(j).Text = "Folder" & j + 1
  Form4.TabControl1.TabPages(j).Controls.Add(chkbx)
  chkbx.Text = "FolderName"
  chkbx.Size = New Size(220, 17)
  chkbx.Name="A" & j  <----- set unique name/key to each control
Next (j)
```

and use `Controls.Find()` method to get the reference of `control`.

```
Dim name = "A0"
Dim controlArray = Me.Controls.Find(name, True)
If controlArray.Length <> 0  Then
   Dim chk As CheckBox = CType(controlArray(0), CheckBox)
   If Not IsNothing(chk) Then
       MsgBox(chk.Checked)
   End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

To go along with what AVD said create your CheckBox's in your Loop where you allocate your dynamic TabPages. You will need either to precreate your combobox's or dynamically create them in another for loop. I would then use their Tag Property to assign an unique ID to each CheckBox and use it to differentiate which one was changed in a Common CheckedChanged Event. Something like this.

```
Dim index As Integer = 0
For j = 1 To 10 '#10 tab pages considered 
    Dim startLocation As Point = New Point(10, 10)
    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(New TabPage)
    TabControl1.TabPages(j).Text = "Folder" & j + 1
    For x = 0 To 7
        Dim chkbx As New CheckBox
        TabControl1.TabPages(j).Controls.Add(chkbx)
        chkbx.Tag = index
        chkbx.Text = "FolderName"
        chkbx.Location = startLocation
        chkbx.Size = New Size(220, 17)
        AddHandler chkbx.CheckedChanged, AddressOf CheckBox_CheckedChanged
        startLocation.Y = startLocation.Y + 16
        index += 1
    Next
Next
```

**CheckChanged Event**

```
Private Sub CheckBox_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim cb As CheckBox = CType(sender, CheckBox)

    Select Case CInt(cb.Tag)
        Case 0

        Case 1

        Case 2

        Case 3

        Case .... 'Up to how ever many index's that you have

        Case Else

    End Select

End Sub
```